# How do I insertContentControl() at the very end of a document

Tags: javascript, openxml, word-addins

In javascript, I wish to insert a call to insertContentControl() at the very end of the document, after any text in the main body. I thought I could do it with:

```html
      context.document.getSelection();
      var cc = context.document.body.insertContentControl();
      cc.color = 'orange';
      cc.tag = 'wikindx-bibliography';
      cc.title = 'Bibliography';
      cc.insertHtml('A reference', "End");
```

But that simply incorporates existing text in the content control then appends 'A reference' to the content control.

Answer (score 0):

This works . . .

```html
      context.document.body.paragraphs.getLast().select("End");
      var sel = context.document.getSelection();
      sel.insertParagraph('', "After");
      sel.insertParagraph('', "After");
      context.document.body.paragraphs.getLast().select("End");
      sel = context.document.getSelection();
      var cc = sel.insertContentControl();
      cc.color = 'orange';
      cc.tag = 'wikindx-bibliography';
      cc.title = 'Bibliography';
      cc.insertHtml('A reference', "End");
```

(With a couple of empty paragraphs as spacers.)